# Float read as int in C++

Tags: c++, io, floating-point, fstream, cin

I have a file in which there are 3 space separated floats on each line. I have written a simple program to read from file and display the read input. But for some reason first value's decimal part is being discarded.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

ifstream f("pointcloud.csv", f.in);
float x[100], y[100], z[100];
int i = 0;

for(std::string line; std::getline(f, line); )   //read stream line by line
{
    std::istringstream in(line);      //make a stream for the line itself


    in >> x[i] >> y[i] >> z[i++];
    
}


for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    cout  << x[i] << " " << y[i] << " " << z[i] << endl;
}
f.close();
return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
429372.16 3680107.43 76.91
429371.55 3680107.73 75.92
429371.54 3680107.65 75.93
...
```

Output:

```
429372 3680107.43 76.91
429371 3680107.73 75.92
429371 3680107.65 75.93
...
```

why the decimal part of all X's are missing?

Comment: Tip: In C++ steer away from C-style fixed-length arrays and towards things like `std::vector`. In situations like this, consider making a simple `struct point` that has your `x`, `y` and `z` properties, then use `std::vector<point>` with `push_back` or `emplace_back` as necessary. Managing multiple arrays, especially arbitrarily fixed-length ones, is a huge mess. As a bonus you can write an `operator>>` for your `point` type that operates directly on the stream, as in `point p; f >> p`.

Comment: Tip: Lines like `in >> x[i] >> y[i] >> z[i++];` are highly problematic. Are you *sure* the `i++` executes when you think it does?

Comment: `cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << x[i] <<` ...

Comment: @tadman: According to [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), since C++17, there is a sequence point between the operands of `>>`. Therefore, I don't see a problem with the line you quoted.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Even if the line does work exactly as intended in this case, it's still "a problem" to write code that's harder to understand. It's not like there's any advantage over putting the `i++` there instead of in the `for` loop, or as its own line following the reads from `in`. Not to mention that we have no reason to think this code is or is not being written for C++17 as opposed to some other version of the standard.

Comment: I'm actually surprised how you were able to store something inside a `float` which is printed as `3680107.43` (the closest single precision IEEE754 number would be `3680107.5` -- of course your compiler could be using something else).

Comment: Six digits of precision is about all you are guaranteed for a `float`. So this result should be within what you expect.

Comment: `429372 3.68011e+06 76.91` This is the first line that I get. If I set the precision to 100 (using `cout.precision(100);`), I get `429372.15625 3680107.5 76.910003662109375`, which is correct, considering you are storing the values as floats.

Comment: Thank you all for replying.
cout.precision(100); showed the correct output.
I should use double as variable type.
@tadman its just a demo program I am aware of stl and its benifits;

Comment: Glad that worked. Don't think of the *Standard Library* as a crutch. It can help you write better code faster. It's just a matter of thinking "What would the Standard Library want me to do?" and at least considering that before hammering out an alternative. Often it saves a ton of time!